# Angularjs handle login and logged in page

Tags: angularjs

I am using 3rd-party client side login then I have `<ng-view>` for every route so It means
all navigate will just reload within `<ng-view>`.

then I have a global footer which display user logged-in info on every partials
So I put it under `<ng-view>`. Will be something like this

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
<div ng-controller="FooterCtrl">User logged-in Info</div>
```

My problems
The FooterCtrl won't display logged-in user info after login because login only reload `<ng-view>` not full reload.  (unless i refresh the page manually using F5).

My questions are,

- how can I hide FooterCtrl when the user is not login
- Where should I put the FooterCtrl?

Answer (score 0):

In your `FooterCtrl` Controller, keep an eye over the route change.

Whenever the route changes, fetch the information on if the user is logged in or not.

Thus, your code will look somewhat like this - In your controller, have the following code:

```js
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (next, current) {
    //Get the current state of the user log in.
    //Accordingly, set the variable

    //If user is logged in
    $scope.userIsLoggedIn = true;

    //Else
    $scope.userIsLoggedIn = false;
});
```

Thus, your scope is now aware if the user is logged in or not each time the route changes - which I assume is, if your application is correctly configured, each time a different template is loaded into `ng-view`.

Now, your view can be as simple as:

```html
<div ng-view>
</div>

<div ng-controller="FooterCtrl">
    <footer ng-show="userIsLoggedIn">
        <!-- Info to show when user is logged in -->
    </footer>

    <footer ng-hide="userIsLoggedIn">
        <!-- Info to show when user is NOT logged in -->
    </footer>
</div>
```

Thus, your Footer displays data based on the log in state of the user. Each time the view template changes, the controller will determine the log in state and display the view accordingly.

Comment: If the entire app is required login. Where is the best place to check if user logged in?

Comment: forgot to mention, I also want the `$scope.userIsLoggedIn` able to use in other routes

Comment: This doesn't really tell how to deal with asynchronous checking.